# What Does The Return Value Of a dispatcher, created by createEventDispatcher in svelte mean?

Tags: event-handling, svelte

The "dispatch" function returned by Svelte's `createEventDispatcher()` has the signature `(type: EventKey, detail?: EventMap[EventKey], options?: DispatchOptions) => boolean`.
What does the returned boolean mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `dispatch` is `true` if any of the listeners called `.preventDefault()` on the event. If no listeners are registerd or none called `.preventDefault()`, the return value is `true`.

[Source](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/220325cd9feea12f9a9bc5eb8df5120f856b1bc9/src/runtime/internal/lifecycle.ts#L75-L99)

Comment: This is explained in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher); also, setting `cancelable` appears to be required.

Comment: * The return value of dispatch is **false** if any of the listeners called .preventDefault() ...